# Event based mysql for php socket?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, sockets

I have a web client that i coded in php/html/javascript/jquery. My client fetches through javascript (in post) data from a mysql server through a php script. I know i could make a php socket server running on that php-apache-mysql box but how do i tell my socket server that a new record on a table of the mysql server has just occurred without checking for new entries every X second, through a crown job? Is there any "event based" system ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Event-based architectures in PHP are notoriously difficult to implement, but because of a number of limitations that make it, to say the least, not the best language for something like this. You would be better doing this in something like Node.js or some other language/environment that is in itself event driven.

PHP is not the best language for this because, amongst other reasons, it cannot be multi-threaded, and you cannot write you own custom non-blocking routines - which puts you at a severe disadvantage when designing a multi-client socket server.

Having said that, if you were to decide to create your socket server in PHP, this could be done, albeit in a slightly horrible way. The basic flow would be something like this:

- [Have a MySQL trigger that calls an external program through something like `sys_exec()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/faqs-triggers.html#qandaitem-B-5-1-10)
- The external program it calls (this could be a PHP script) connects to the running socket server, through whatever means you fancy, maybe a socket connection, maybe shared memory, maybe something else entirely like a POSIX signal, and notifies the socket server process of the new row.
- The socket server can now run a SELECT (or not, maybe you pass whatever data you need from the script above) and do whatever you need to do with the data, and push data to clients.

Answer (score 0):

If you've already set up a socket listener, then you just need to have edit the php script that's in charge of inserting new mysql records so that it sends a signal to the socket when an insertion has successfully taken place. Or perhaps I don't understand your question?

Comment: You understand very well. It's a shared DB and it's not inserted by a script but by a software that i have no control on. But i can do whatever i want with the DB

Comment: Hmm... if you only control the db server it might be pretty ugly. One idea (might be crazy) is to have the php socket listen on the same port as MYSQL is listening on (they'd both have to be set to UDP so they could share the port)... you'd then put a small delay on the PHP script so that insertion could finish and then it would fire.

That's a bit round-about though... If I were doing it I'd probably just add a MYSQL insert trigger to update a timestamp in a single row in another table, and then run a cron job that checks the secondary table (which would be fast, as the table is tiny)

Comment: Yea i was trying to avoid the crown job which breaks the realtime part of it if i can say. The only control i have up on is the sql query that the software uses to insert records. Just pure sql.